# Removal of .orig files

Tags: magento-1, patches, security

In patching some Magento sites the patch leaves behind a `.orig` version of some of the files that were patched. I've been removing these from version control but was curious is there's any purpose to them and why only some of the files have .orig files created for them?

I'm also assuming removing them is also best practice as otherwise you're leaving unpatched files within the code base.